# Divisible by 3 and 4

Tags: statistics

How many 4 digit numbers are divisible by
both 3 and 4? The answer is 750
Is there a shortcut to find the solutions beside factoring it out and compare?
Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To begin, notice that the numbers which are divisible by both $3$ and $4$ are exactly those numbers which are divisible by $12$.  (*In general, the numbers which are divisible by $j$ and $k$ are the numbers divisible by $\text{lcm}(j,k)$*).

To continue, you can notice that the number of numbers strictly greater than zero and less than or equal to $n$ which are divisible by $12$ is equal to $\lfloor\frac{n}{12}\rfloor$.  (*In general, the number of positive integers less than or equal to $n$ which are divisible by $k$ is $\lfloor\frac{n}{k}\rfloor$*)

With this in mind, we see the number of numbers between $m$ and $n$ inclusive (with $m\leq n$) which are divisible by $12$ is $\lfloor\frac{n}{12}\rfloor-\lfloor\frac{m-1}{12}\rfloor$ (*or again, replace $12$ with $k$ to be more general*)

Four digit numbers are those numbers between $1000$ and $9999$, so using the above:

$$\lfloor\frac{9999}{12}\rfloor-\lfloor\frac{999}{12}\rfloor=750$$

As briefly mentioned in comments on another answer, you should be careful about edge-cases for divisibility arguments like this.  For example, the number of numbers divisible by $12$ is different for the range $10\to14$ than $14\to18$ despite the length of the ranges being the same.  In your studies you will not always be so lucky that the length of the range happens to be a multiple of the number you are checking divisibility for.

Comment: thank you for your help

Answer (score 4):

Yes! There is a shortcut. The lowest common multiple (LCM) of 3 and 4 is 12. That means only multiples of 12 are divisible by both 3 and 4. So how many multiples of 12 are there between 1000 to 9999?

There are 9000 numbers between 1000 to 9999. There is a multiple of 12, well, every 12 numbers. Hence 9000/12 = 750.

Answer (score 1):

There is a huge shortcut. *Divisible by both 3 and 4* is equivalent to *divisible by 12*.

There are $9999-999=9000$ 4-digits numbers and 1 out of 12 is divisible by 12, hence the solution is $9000/12=750$.

Comment: That is dangerous since you might run into problems on the edge cases.  Say for example you ask how many integers between $10$ and $14$ are divisible by $12$.  Of course we know the answer should be $1$ from inspection, but you seem to suggest that it would be $\frac{14-10}{12}=\frac{1}{3}$.  Compare this to how many integers are divisible by $12$ which are between $14$ and $18$, also giving $\frac{1}{3}$

Comment: @JMoravitz : you're right, but the problem solves itself when the range is a multpile of 12, which is the case here.